# Autoboxing error

Tags: java, findbugs

FindBugs is telling me I have the following error:

> A primitive is boxed, and then immediately unboxed. This probably is due to a manual boxing in a place where an unboxed value is required, thus forcing the compiler to immediately undo the work of the boxing.

Here's the relevant code:

```
...
String str= "10.0";
Double d = (str != null ? Double.valueOf(str) : new Double(0.0));
...
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried splitting this line into multiple ones and thus seeing which part findbugs exactly means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a bug in FindBugs to me. If you compile that code and then run `javap -c` on it, it never calls `doubleValue()` which is what normally gets used for unboxing.

Admittedly you might want to use a cached `Double` for zero, rather than allocating one every time this is executed, but other than that it looks reasonable to me...

I suggest you report this to the FindBugs team.

EDIT: Before reporting this to the FindBugs team, I'd update your question with a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. I took your word for it that the code you showed us was the code FindBugs was complaining about. If that's not the case, all bets are off :)

Comment: I thought otherwise, but you're right: since both expressions in the conditional are of type `Double`, the entire conditional expression has the same time: no un-boxing (and re-boxing) is necessary. This would be different if the first expression where `Double.parseDouble(str)`.

Comment: Since FindBugs analyses byte code, maybe this is a compiler issue?

Comment: @muisKk: No, because if you look at my answer, you'll see that I've run `javap` on the byte code too - and never seen `doubleValue` which is used for unboxing.

Comment: But you don't know which compiler the OP used...?

Comment: @MusiKk: That's true. This would be a pretty odd compiler bug though... I think it's more likely that the OP hasn't actually posted the code which is causing FindBugs issues.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you try to answer http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/158353/why-does-the-code-auditing-tools-like-findbugs-require-a-compile-step-to-work-pr

Answer (score 3):

I tryed your code - FindBugs doesn't display any error. I think that this code significally different from that produces error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any auto-boxing or unboxing.

```
double d = str == null ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(str);
```

The moral is, don't use a Object when you mean to use a primitive.

IMHO Its less confusing to use positive expression instead of negative and double negative boolean expressions.